# How to get the Subroutine Sender name

Tags: wpf, vb.net, variables, declaration, sender

When I click the Button1 the MsgBox shows me "1" which is good.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    MsgBox(CType(sender, Button).Name.Replace("Button", ""))
End Sub
```

I want the MsgBox shows me "30" when I click the Button2.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Hello30()
End Sub

Sub Hello30()
    'The following line is need to be repaired.
    MsgBox(CType(sender, ????).Name.Replace("Hello", ""))
End Sub
```

Comment: Pass the sender in as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure what you're trying to do, but this is an example that'll get you close:

```
Imports System.Reflection
        
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Hello30()
End Sub

Sub Hello30()
    Dim method As String = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod.Name
    MsgBox(method.Replace("Hello", ""))
End Sub
```